# Call macros in a for loop

Tags: twig

Is it possible within `twig` to call a macro in a for loop by passing variables from the loop into the macro call?

For example:

```
{% for formElem in formElems %}
  {{ forms.elem({{ formElem.type }}, {{ formElem.name }}, {{ formElem.value }}) }}
{% endfor %}
```

By the way, I know the above syntax doesn't work because I tried it and got an error, but nevertheless, is it possible to pass variables to a macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your syntax to this:

```
{% for formElem in formElems %}
    {{ forms.elem(formElem.type, formElem.name, formElem.value) }}
{% endfor %}
```

You don't need to use the `{{ }}` to pass a twig variable to a twig macro